# Requests in Django

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I'm newer in `Django` and some time ago I've totally stuck on problems with my requests. I'm trying to do `POST` from `Django` form. I do that with `json` and `AJAX`
Here is my code

form.py

```
    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Message
            fields = ['message_text']
            widgets = {
                'message_text': forms.TextInput(
                    attrs={'id': 'message_text', 'required': True,
                          'placeholder': 'new message...', }),}
```

views.py

```
    def index(request):
        if  request.method == 'POST':
            form = PostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.cleaned_data
                message_t = request.POST.get('message_text')
                response_data = {}
                new_mess = Message(message_text = message_t, 
                                  post_time = message_t.created,
                                  username="second")      
                new_mess.save()
                response_data['result'] = message_t   
            else:
                response_data['result'] = 'nothing...'
        else:
            form = PostForm()       
        template = loader.get_template('chat/index.html') 
        context = RequestContext(request, {  
                         'form': form, })         
         return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

(In another variant of views.py I tried to separate POST request handling to another function, but it doesn't work as well)

html:

```
    <form method="POST" id="post-form">
        <td class="col-lg-6"><div class="fieldWrapper" id="the_post"
            class="form-control" type="text">
            {{ form.message_text }}
        </div></td>
        <td class="col-lg-6"> <input type="submit" value="Post" 
            class="btn btn-success" name = "Post"></td>
    </form>
```

js:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
        create_post();
    });


    function create_post() {
        console.log("create post is working!") // sanity check
        $.ajax({
        url : "/chat/new_message/", // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { the_post : $('#post-form').val() }, 

        success : function(json) {
            $('#post-form').val(''); // remove the value from the input
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
            console.log("success");
        },

        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
           ...
        }
            });
        };
    });
```

In the result my `POST` is successful, no error appears, but no record in the base created too. 
Note: Also I've excluded `csrf` everywere

Can someone help me to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: in your view, what is the use of the line `form.cleaned_data` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the fix for my POST.
The main problem was in json body, I was using wrong value name, it has to be:

```
    data : { the_post : $('#message_text').val() },
```

Now request is not empty.

Comment: Another problem was in variables naming.
All reference to entity should have the same name, otherwise form will be not valid. Correct json in my case is:
 ' $.ajax({
      url : "/chat/new_message/", 
      type : "POST", 
      dataType: "json",
      data : { message_text : $('#message_text').val() },'

Answer (score 1):

The form is not valid. It can never be valid, because you are sending a JSON dictionary with the form data inside the key "the_post", but you haven't told the view to look there.

And the view can't report back the status of the form, because you construct a response - "response_data" - and then ignore it.

Finally, your view does not send back JSON anyway - it sends back the rendered template, as if it were a normal non-Ajax view - so the receiving JS has no idea what to do with it.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try to do something with that.
Now I see that I've missed response, but it was in one of my previous variants :)